# Let R be a ring. Can a left(or right) divisor of $0$ have more than one element in the ring so that $X*a = 0$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Currently i'm trying to prove that if in a ring $R$ exists a left divisor of $0$ there must be a right divisor of $0$ as well.

I've tried the following : Let $x$ be a divisor of $0$ in the ring $R$ .
Then for a certain $a \in R$ it is true that $ x*a = 0$.
Using the associativity of $*$ it means that $(x*a)*x = x *(a*x) $

$x*a = 0$ that means $0*x = x*(a*x)$

$0 = x*(a*x)$
 I've proved that $a*x$ is not equal to $a$ . Does that mean $a*x$ is another element for which $x$ is a divisor of $0$ ? Or does it mean that $(a * x)$ = 0 ?

Another questions : if $x$ is a left and right divisor of $0$ in $R$ ( that means $x*a = 0$ and $b*x = 0$ for certain $a$ and $b$ in $R$ ) does that mean $a=b$?

Comment: Can you define a left zero divisor ? If you define it correctly, the first question will be easily answered. As for the second question , why don't you try with matrices ?

Answer (score 1):

Take the abelian group

$$S:=\left\{\;(a_1,a_2,...)\;/\;a_k\in\Bbb Z\;\right\}\;,\;\;\text{with componentwise addition}$$

And now check the elements

$$L,R,P_1\in\text{End}_\Bbb Z(S)\;,\;\;\begin{cases}L(a_1,a_2,...):=(a_2,a_3,...)\\{}\\R(a_1,a_2,...):=(0,a_1,a_2,...)\\{}\\
P_1(a_1,a_2,...):=(a_1,0,0,...)\end{cases}$$

Observe that $\;P_1R=0=LP_1\;$ , so $\;L\;$ is a left zero divisor and $\;R\;$ is a right zero divisor, but none of them is a zero divisor of the other side (try to prove this by yourself: what is $\;LR\;$ , and even more interesting: what is $\;RL\;$ ...)

If you want, you can also take the ring of all real bounded (or even real convergent) sequences instead of $\;S\;$ , or something similar...or complex ones, etc.